# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed Incompatible padding mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fingerprint-api

I am learning Android Development and tried to work on Fingerprint Authentication So I watch a video on Youtube about it and do the same thing shown in that video, First, there is try-catch block through which my app doesn't crash but I'm unable to find the error so I removed the Try-Catch block. While I am doing this I got this error. Here is my Main Activity Code.

```
package com.jayu.learningnewthings

import android.Manifest
import android.app.KeyguardManager
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import java.lang.Exception
import java.security.KeyStore
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.SecretKey

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
class FingerPrintActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var fm : FingerprintManager
    lateinit var km : KeyguardManager
    lateinit var keyStore : KeyStore
    lateinit var keyGenerator: KeyGenerator
    var keyName = "FingerPrint"
    lateinit var cipher: Cipher
    lateinit var cryptoObject: FingerprintManager.CryptoObject

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finger_print)

        km = getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        fm = getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE) as FingerprintManager

        if (!km.isKeyguardSecure){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lock Screen Not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }
        if (!fm.hasEnrolledFingerprints()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enroll one fingerprint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT), 111)
        }
        else{
            validateFingerPrint()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 111 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            validateFingerPrint()
        }
    }

    private fun validateFingerPrint() {
        //Generating Key

        //Catch 1
        try{
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,"AndroidKeyStore")
            keyStore.load(null)
            keyGenerator.init(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName
                    ,KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                    .build())
            keyGenerator.generateKey()
        }catch (e : Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        //Initialize of Cryptography

        if (initCipher()) {
            cipher.let {
                cryptoObject = FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(it)
            }
            val helper = FingerPrintHelper(this)

            if (fm != null && cryptoObject != null){
                helper.startAuth(fm,cryptoObject)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initCipher(): Boolean {
            val cipherAlgorithm = "${KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES}/${KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC}/${KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7}"
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm)

            keyStore.load(null)

            val key = keyStore.getKey(keyName,null) as SecretKey
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key)

            return true
    }
}
```

The Full-stack of error is

```
    App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
    $ adb shell am start -n "com.jayu.learningnewthings/com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Connected to process 19230 on device 'Pixel_2_API_29 [emulator-5554]'.
    Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
    I/arningnewthing: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    E/arningnewthing: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
    W/arningnewthing: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
    D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
    W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:231): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7194 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c142,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.jayu.learningnewthings
    W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
    D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    W/arningnewthing: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    W/arningnewthing: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.jayu.learningnewthings, PID: 19230
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jayu.learningnewthings/com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity}: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
         Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
            at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1362)
            at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1402)
            at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
            at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
            at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
            at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
            at com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity.initCipher(FingerPrintActivity.kt:111)
            at com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity.validateFingerPrint(FingerPrintActivity.kt:82)
            at com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity.onCreate(FingerPrintActivity.kt:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
         Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible padding mode
            at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1292)
            at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1402) 
            at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54) 
            at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89) 
            at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265) 
            at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109) 
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984) 
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891) 
            at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796) 
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773) 
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143) 
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084) 
            at com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity.initCipher(FingerPrintActivity.kt:111) 
            at com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity.validateFingerPrint(FingerPrintActivity.kt:82) 
            at com.jayu.learningnewthings.FingerPrintActivity.onCreate(FingerPrintActivity.kt:51) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Please answer if anybody knows how to resolve it.
Thank you in advance